# How do I access last item in an array in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, indexing, fortran

In Matlab, `end` index lets me access a last item.

```
> array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
> array(end)
ans =  7
```

How do I do the same in Fortran?

```
program hello
   integer array(7)
   array = (/1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7/)
!print *, array(end)
!               1
!Error: Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)

! print *, array(-1)
!                1
!Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (-1 < 1) in dimension 1

! print *, array(0)
!                1
!Warning: Array reference at (1) is out of bounds (0 < 1) in dimension 1
end program Hello
```

Comment: Why did you tag this as Matlab?  Seems like a Fortran question.

Comment: It may be impossible, e.g., if the array is assumed size dummy argument.

Answer (score 20):

```
array ( ubound (array) )
```

`size` will only work if the array is 1-indexed.

Comment: NB: If you have a multi-dimensional array, you would need to specify `array(ubound(array,dim=n))` where `n` is the dimension you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. @KyleKanos Using your suggestion, I found that if I wanted to pull the last element of a particular row, the following was necessary `array(n,ubound(array,dim=n))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

there is no such convenience notation, you need to do this

```
 array(size(array))
```

in older fortran versions you dont even have  `size()` and need to track the dimension yourself

worth a note fortran arrays can be defined to have negative indices, so the end notation used in some other languages would be ambiguous