# How to mimic python's negative indexing of arrays in Fortran?

Tags: python, arrays, fortran

In python, negative array indexing can be used to access the array starting from the end. This is particularly useful if you use e.g. arrays with circular boundary conditions.

Can we mimic this in Fortran, without using IF clauses?

What I want to obtain in Fortran, for example, is that by issuing

```
myarray(-1)
```

I get the last element of the array (and similar with all other elements).

Comment: maybe something like `myarray( myarray.length -1)` or its equivalent in frontran

Comment: Why does this need a Python tag?

Comment: That looks useful until you realize that `myarray(-1)` is an actual element in your array and you need it for those very boundary conditions so that you can start the real PDE domain at element 1 (or 0 if you wish so) and not at element 3. Fortran simply isn't Python. Don't write Python in Fortran and don't write Fortran in Python, you will confuse the readers of your code.

Comment: *This is particularly useful if you use e.g. arrays with circular boundary conditions.*  As for Python I haven't a scooby, but in Fortran the intrinsic `cshift` is useful for manipulating arrays with circular boundary conditions.  I rather concur with @VladimirF that you should write Fortran in Fortran and Python in Python.  Perhaps if we knew why you want what you want we could provide more useful and more Fortranny guidance.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for pointing me to `cshift`. I'll take a look at it. What I want to do is to avoid to insert `if` clauses inside a `do` loop that may or may not require the insertion of periodic BC due to the index going negative. If this cannot be done in a "fortranny" way, then I guess that would be the answer one can provide.

Comment: since Fortran supports arbitrary indexing, you can very well have arrays that actually use negative index values -- so a python-esque usage of negative indices to count backward from the end would be incompatible.

Comment: Usually the boundary condition is the same for the whole side of the domain and therefore there is only one if condition and the loops or array copies are inside it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access last item in an array in Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986269/how-do-i-access-last-item-in-an-array-in-fortran)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last element using:

```
myarray(size(myarray))
```

or the element before the last:

```
myarray(size(myarray) - 1)
```

Note that this will only work with a 1-indexed array. If you are not sure, you can use `ubound`.

Comment: you need to add one to make `-1` reference the last element, though for consistency with 1- indexing maybe we want zero to point to the end anyway.